# With jquery i can't get links working AND animate an anchors' background

Tags: jquery, html

With jquery i can't get links working AND animate the anchors' background both.
It seems that either one or the other works.

This is the markup:

```
   <ul class="nav">
   <li> <span id="background"> </span><span id="active"></span><a href="page1.html"     
   class="active">page 1</a> </li>
   <li> <a href="page2.html">page 2</a> </li>
   </ul>
```

This is the jquery code with which the clicking action happens but not the animation effect:

```
$("ul.nav a").click(function () {
     $("span#background").fadeIn(800, function () {});
     $("#active").animate({left: "+=2410"}, 950)     
   });
```

The "span" elements have background images via css which is dynamically placed within the active listelement. Thus the active link gets a background and an animated image flying in.
When inserting "return false;" at the end of the jquery code, the animation does run but clicking action is killed.

this is the bare bones testpage:
[link to testpage](http://www.vuyk.eu/testsite/page1.html)

Thanks anyone who can help!

Comment: Have you tried to update jQuery from v1.5 to the latest?

Comment: Just did the update, this did not change the behaviour of the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your above **snippet** as well as your **testpage** and the problem is you want to have a single click that allows the anchor to follow the href AND show animations at the same time.

There is a better solution. That's to have the animations occur during mouse over via jQuery `.hover()` method. Reference [**HERE**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

The **testpage** example using .hover() is here: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jgPF8/)

I took the liberty in changing the animations a bit, but you should get the idea along with the many comments I put in to understand the flow/concept.

If the `.hover()` method is not acceptable, then it's still possible to use a single onclick for everything but then no animations will happen during mouse-over. This [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UmnEC/1/) uses `.click()` instead.

Because `.hover()` is then used for animations, the `anchor tag` still can be allowed to function normally when it's clicked on.

Comment: You made a lot of work from this answer! Thanks... I like the exact way that you use to calculate the hiding distance for .brush - my method was a bit rough, just way out of the viewport.

Comment: Hi, I think the rest of my comment was accidently erased.
Altough your method is a nice alternative, it is not the goal of the question to achieve a hover effect. 

"If the .hover() method is not acceptable, then it's still possible to use a single onclick for everything but then no animations will happen during mouse-over." 

This is what I tryed to accomplish, the hover effect is not neccesary as it will be added by css.
Up to now either the link OR the animation works.